# not a valid virtual path - when trying to return a file from a url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

We download a file from our CdN and then return a url to that downloaded file to the user.  I'm trying to get this implemented so that when a user clicks the download buttton, it goes and test that url to that downloaded file then forces a save prompt based on that local url.

So for example if there is a button called download on the page for a specific .pdf, we ultimately have code in our controller going to the cdn and downloading the file, zipping it then returning a url such as:  http://www.ourLocalAssetServer.com/assets/20120331002728.zip

I'm not sure if you you can use the File() method to return the resource to the user as to cause a save prompt when you have a url to the file, not a system directory virtual path.

So how can I get this working with the url?  I need the download button to ultimately force a save prompt on their end given a url such as what is generated per this example above?  Not I am using POST, not a GET, so not sure which I should use in this case either besides this not working overall to force a save prompt.  It is hitting my GetFileDownloadUrl but ultimately errors saying it's not a virtual path.

Here's my code:

```
@foreach (CarFileContent fileContent in ModelCarFiles)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("GetFileDownloadUrl", "Car", FormMethod.Get, new { carId = Model.CarId, userId = Model.UserId, @fileCdnUrl = fileContent.CdnUrl }))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("userId", Model.UserId);
        @Html.Hidden("carId", Model.CarId);
        @Html.Hidden("fileCdnUrl", fileContent.CdnUrl);        
        <p><input type="submit" name="SubmitCommand" value="download" /> @fileContent.Name</p>
    }
}

    public ActionResult GetFileDownloadUrl(string fileCdnUrl, int carId, int userId)
    {
        string downloadUrl = string.Empty;

        // take the passed Cdn Url and go and download that file to one of our other servers so the user can download that .zip file
        downloadUrl = GetFileZipDownloadUrl(carId, userId, fileCdnUrl;

        // now we have that url to the downloaded zip file e.g. http://www.ourLocalAssetServer.com/assets/20120331002728.zip
        int i = downloadUrl.LastIndexOf("/");

        string fileName = downloadUrl.Substring(i);

        return File(downloadUrl, "application/zip", fileName);
    }
```

error: not a valid virtual path

Answer (score 0):

This won't work except the zip file is in your virtual path.

The File method you have used here File(string, string, string) expects a fileName which will be used to create a FilePathResult.

Another option would be to download it (using WebClient.DownloadData or DownloadFile methods) and passing either the byte array or the file path (depending on which you choose).

```
var webClient = new Webclient();
byte[] fileData = webClient.DownloadData(downloadUrl);

return File(fileData, "application/zip", fileName);
```

And the lines where you get the index of "/" just to get the filename is unnecessary as you could have used:

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(downloadUrl);
```